# Cannot launch AVD in emulator and Gradle won't build

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-emulator

I created my first project on android studio2. But when I press green triangle button and create a virtual device (Nexus4) an error came:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.

Output

Hax is enabled

Hax ram_size 0x60000000

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555

emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: No error

none.xml:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document

emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '25.1.7'6ce&amp;os=Windows&amp;version=25.1.7.0&amp;coreVersion=qemu2%202.2.0">Found</a>
```

I only added this code:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
```

To the android block in build.gradle(Module:app), because of another error:

```
(failed to resolve junit)
```

I also get a lot more errors at Messages Gradle Build: http://pastebin.com/3K30mApG

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app.gradle` and change
`buildToolsVersion` to `buildToolsVersion: "23.0.2"`

Comment: I got this: failed to find Build tools 23.0.2 and sync 23.0.2

Comment: what version of java are you using?

Comment: I have jdk 1.8.0_92

Comment: change the `buildToolsVersion` to previous value and try to use jdk 1.7

Comment: How to use jdk 1.7?

Comment: @future2020 download it and go to File->Project Structure and select it from there

Comment: I had jdk 1.8 but android studio was set to use jdk 1.7 so I change it to jdk 1.8